# Keep the files of two projects in a solution synchronized

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Supposed I have a solution with two simple C# projects in it. If I added a .cs file to one project, is there any way to reflect this change in the other project?

As an example, XNA allowed Xbox 360, Windows and Windows Phone projects to be kept in the same solution. If a file was added to one, it would be automatically added to the other two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a file to one project first and then add the same file as existing item to the other project and select `Add as Link` option. This way it creates a link and not a copy of the file.

1. Select a project, right-click, select Add -> Existing Item.
2. Select a file and change the `Add` button to `Add as Link`.

See more in [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234).

You have to add the file manually first though.